# My BFS recursive call does not stop

Tags: java, graph

I have the following code to find all the paths between starting and ending node .

Graph.java

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Set;

public class Graph {
private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map = new HashMap();

public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
        map.put(node1, adjacent);
    }
    adjacent.add(node2);
}

public void addTwoWayVertex(String node1, String node2) {
    addEdge(node1, node2);
    addEdge(node2, node1);
}

public boolean isConnected(String node1, String node2) {
    Set adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return adjacent.contains(node2);
}

public LinkedList<String> adjacentNodes(String last) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(last);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return new LinkedList();
    }
    return new LinkedList<String>(adjacent);
}
```

}

and 
Search.java

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 public class Search {

private static final String START = "D";
private static final String END = "E";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this graph is directional
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    graph.addEdge("A", "B");
    graph.addEdge("A", "C");
    graph.addEdge("B", "A");
    graph.addEdge("B", "D");
    graph.addEdge("B", "E"); // this is the only one-way connection
    graph.addEdge("B", "F");
    graph.addEdge("C", "A");
    graph.addEdge("C", "E");
    graph.addEdge("C", "F");
    graph.addEdge("D", "B");
    graph.addEdge("E", "C");
    graph.addEdge("E", "F");
    graph.addEdge("F", "B");
    graph.addEdge("F", "C");
    graph.addEdge("F", "E");
    LinkedList<String> visited = new LinkedList();
    visited.add(START);
    new Search().breadthFirst(graph, visited);
}

private void breadthFirst(Graph graph, LinkedList<String> visited) {
    LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
    // examine adjacent nodes
    for (String node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node.equals(END)) {
            visited.add(node);
            printPath(visited);
            visited.removeLast();
            return ;
            //break;
        }
    }
    // in breadth-first, recursion needs to come after visiting adjacent nodes
    for (String node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node) || node.equals(END)) {
            continue;
        }
        visited.addLast(node);
        breadthFirst(graph, visited);
        visited.removeLast();
    }
}

private void printPath(LinkedList<String> visited) {
    for (String node : visited) {
        System.out.print(node);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I want to stop the recursive call after finding the first path between the two nodes . the return statement before break statement works fine but if i add many undirected edges it does not stop printing the all paths between two nodes .

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

In BFS, you have to "color" the nodes to know if you visited them already.

http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/GraphAlgor/breadthSearch.htm

To keep track of progress, breadth-first-search colors each vertex. Each vertex of the graph is in one of three states:

1. Undiscovered;
2. Discovered but not fully explored; and
3. Fully explored.

The state of a vertex, u, is stored in a color variable as follows:

1. color[u] = White - for the "undiscovered" state,
2. color [u] = Gray - for the "discovered but not fully explored" state, and
3. color [u] = Black - for the "fully explored" state.